# Firebase new pricing offers Full Google Cloud platform integration, what that would mean in terms of App Engine and Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions

It is unclear what this means if i want to run a node instance/worker on App engine or a simple node function using google cloud functions. would i be able to trigger them when data is changed in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

This week Google Cloud Functions went into beta. We also released an [integration between Cloud Functions and Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). This allows you to run your JavaScript functions on Google Cloud's infrastructure in response to Firebase Database writes.

But using a Node.js process on an App Engine Flexible Environment is also still a valid option to run code in response to database events. It all depends on your needs which is better suited.

Comment: thanks Frank, I have been using Google cloud function for some time now, and I love it .

Comment: Hi guys, I currently using GAE with firebase-queue to handle concurrency,  I am currently facing a lot problem with firebase-queue, transaction disconnect issue. Should I remove the queue and write code only in response to DB events or cloud functions.